# can apache cxf-ws client 2.7.3 support TLS with SHA-2

Tags: apache, cxf, webservice-client, sha256

We have an app that was developed by devs that are not around anymore and I am not well versed in cxf. But it is being used for posting xml requests (SOAP style but not really soap) to an endpoint that in two weeks we were told is dropping support for SHA-1 and will only support SHA-2/TLS.

I can tell from the code that we accept any certificate however not sure if apache cxf client 2.7.3 actually supports SHA-2.

The test endpoint of our partner is currently down and not sure how soon it will be available for testing so I tried to figure out if SHA-2 was supported from documentation but could not find any thing.

Any pointer is really appreciated.

org.apache.cxf:cxf-ws-client:2.7.3

Thank you in advance